# PDF thumbnail not appearing

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

PDF file in Text & Media element won't show.

**I added** two PDF and one image. As you can see from generated markup, the PDF come out empty, while the image shows:

[image]

**Have tried** all tests in Install tool. Every test succeeded except *Render text with TrueType font using 'niceText' option* ([screenshot](http://prnt.sc/cesdtg))

Comment: do the tests work with PDF in the Install Tool?

Comment: Have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause for non-working PDF thumbnails is that Ghostscript is not installed. You can check that in the TYPO3 install tool.

Another possibility would be a misconfiguration of ImageMagick in TYPO3, especially the version (`im_version_5` setting and friends).

As the problem only occurs in the frontend, you should also check if the path is correct and/or if you have any permission problems writing to typo3temp/. If that is all correct, try flushing the processed files cache (in the install tool) and check if the thumbnails in the backend appear correctly again.

Comment: `exec("'gs' '--version'",$output);` in PHP returns 9.05. Gave www-data all access in typo3temp recursively. No change. Not sure how to configure ImageMagick.

Comment: As Georg pointed out above, did you try the PDF-related image tests in the install tool? If they fail, please post error messages/screenshots if the images look weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed ghostscript via brew, ghostscript is installed in /usr/local/bin. You need a symlink to ghostscript in /usr/bin/

1. Restart mac
2. CMD + R on restart.
3. Start terminal
4. run `csrutil disable`
5. Normal Restart
6. sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs
7. Restart again with CMD + R and open terminal
8. run `csrutil enable` to enable System Integration Security again.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/9913753/chriskr for the csrutil hint